# SQL query to find a list of city names that dont start with vowels

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query the list of CITY names from table - STATION that do not start with vowels with results that cannot contain duplicates.
The table just has id, city, population

This is the query that I've written

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY RLIKE '[^bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ].*';
```

This gives a wrong answer. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try the `NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*$'`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*$'
```

Answer (score 13):

A `^` in regular expressions can have different meanings, depending on its location. When it's the first character in a regex, it refers to the start of the string. But when it's the first character in a set, like `[^abc]`, it means `not one of`. And when it appears elsewhere, it just refers to the `^` itself.

So you would need something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY RLIKE '^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ].*';
```

or, just exclude the letters you don't want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY RLIKE '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*';
```

Answer (score 7):

```
select distinct city from station 
where city Not like 'A%' and city Not like 'E%' and city Not like 'I%' and
      city Not like 'o%' and city not like 'U%';
```

Comment: minor: that should be a capital O.

Answer (score 6):

Query the list of CITY names from `STATION` that either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels. IN ORACLE

```
select distinct city 
from station 
where regexp_like(city, '^[^aeiouAEIOU]|*[^aeiouAEIOU]$');
```

In MySQL -

```
 select distinct city 
 from station 
 where city RLIKE '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*' OR 
 city RLIKE '^.*[^aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried this.

```
select distinct city
from station
where substring(city,1,1) not in('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select DISTINCT CITY from STATION where CITY NOT LIKE '[a,e,i,o,u]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou].*';
```

MySQL Ref.: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct city from station where city regexp
'^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$'
```

If your query doesn't starts and ends with a vowel.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example without regular expressions

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    City 
FROM Station
WHERE LEFT(City, 1) NOT IN ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u");
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql we can use this.

```
select distinct city from station where city regexp '^[^aeiou].*';
```

[To Know More About MySQL Regular Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html)

For Oracle we can use

```
select distinct(city) from station where regexp_like (city, '^[^AEIOU](*)');
```

[To Know More About Oracle Regular Expression](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php)

For MS SQL Server

```
select distinct city from station where city not like '[aeuio]%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station
WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou]'
```

MySQL accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked on MS SQL SERVER:

```
select distinct city from station where city NOT like '[aeuio]%' Order by City;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL:

```
Select DISTINCT CITY
FROM
STATION
Where CITY NOT LIKE 'A%' AND CITY NOT LIKE 'E%' AND CITY NOT LIKE 'I%' AND CITY NOT LIKE 'O%' AND CITY NOT LIKE 'U%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select distinct city from station where city  not RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE
LOWER(SUBSTR(CITY,LENGTH(CITY),1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct City from Station where City Like '[^aeiou]%';
```

MS SQL Server Tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT city from STATION
 WHERE city NOT LIKE "[aieuo]%[aieuo] [aieuo]%[aieuo]"
 AND city NOT LIKE "[aieuo]%[aieuo]";
```

The first NOT LIKE means, that each word of the two-word city names doesn't start and end with vowels. The second NOT LIKE is for one-word city names.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from station where (
    left(city,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u') 
    and  
    right(city,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u')
);
```

Comment: PLease add some explanation why this code answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

In ORACLE:

```
select 
distinct(city)
from station
where regexp_like (city, '^[^A|E|I|O|U](*)');
```

There is no need to specify the ending letter in this solution.  It's not called out for in the problem presented.

Comment: Between the two carots ( ^^ ) and after the U, there should be [ ].  They didn't post for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from station where city regexp '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$'
```

**distinct:** to avoid the duplication on the following column

**regexp:** MySql function ([regexp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)) to obtain Regular Expressions. expression starts with `^` and ends with `$`. In Oracle its `regexp_like (city,'RegEx')` [Regular Expressions With Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm).

`[^...]` means any character NOT contain any of `...`
`[^...].` means a single character NOT contain any of `...`
`[^...].*` means first character NOT contain any of `...`
`[^...].*[^...]` means first character NOT contains any of `...` AND not ends with `...`
`[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]` mean the first character NOT starts with vowels AND not ends with vowels

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with this

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION
WHERE CITY NOT LIKE 'a%' 
AND CITY NOT LIKE 'e%'
AND CITY NOT LIKE 'i%'
AND CITY NOT LIKE 'o%'
AND CITY NOT LIKE 'u%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct <COLUMN NAME> from <table name>
WHERE SUBSTRING(<COLUMN NAME>,1,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')
order by <COLUMN NAME>
```

Distinct words do not start with a vowel.

Comment: SUBSTRING(<COLUMN NAME>,1,1)

Comment: Could you please add a bit more of context to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from station where REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(city),'^[^aeiou].*.[^aeiou]$');
```

[^aeiou] Does not accept aeiou.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct city from station where
city not in
(select distinct city from station where
 (city like "A%" or
city like "E%" or
 city like "I%" or
 city like "O%" or
 city like "U%"
));
```

This will work i guess.

Answer (score -1):

for oracle

```
select distinct 
    city 
from station 
where regexp_like(city, '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*');
```